# How to target specific point in Cesium pointprimitivecollection?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm working on how to show/hide points in order to filter data that I'm displaying in a PointPrimitiveCollection on a Cesium globe. I know you can target by index number but I'm wondering if there's a way to add some sort of metadata to the points so that I can target them based on those values?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property after the point is created (this line: `points.add({
                position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude),
                color : color
            }).customId = [longitude, latitude];`).
Here's a code that works:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var points = viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.PointPrimitiveCollection());

for (var longitude = -180; longitude < 180; longitude++) {
    var color = Cesium.Color.PINK;
    if ((longitude % 2) === 0) {
        color = Cesium.Color.CYAN;
    }

    for (var latitude = -90; latitude < 90; latitude++) {
        points.add({
            position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude),
            color : color
        }).customId = [longitude, latitude];
    }
}

var red = false;
setInterval(function() {
  var myPoints = points._pointPrimitives.filter(function(point){return point.customId[1] > -20 && point.customId[1] < 20;});
  red = !red;
  myPoints.forEach(function(point) {
    point.color = red ? Cesium.Color.GREEN : Cesium.Color.RED;
  })
}, 2000);
```

This code toggles the color of the points between -20 and 20 in latitude.  You can set any custom property you want and play with it (note - this code is not optimal in any way and is just for demo).
Working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/DxWMwfdr4L5pfHRlVmlX?p=preview